# Jquery Facebook API Feed suddenly stopped working - April 8th 2015

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I was recently tasked with implementing a jquery Facebook wall (pulled from my company's public fb page) on the homepage of our company website.

After some trial and error, I managed to get it working very satisfactorily using this plugin: https://github.com/thomasclausen/jquery-facebook-wall

It worked for a couple of weeks until yesterday when it suddenly stopped working (halfway through the day). None of my site files were edited during that time.

The demo on the above GitHub link is also broken and showing the same symptoms as my website (ie. the unordered list where the content is supposed to load remains empty).

Chrome dev tools shows no errors and it appears from the network tab of dev tools that the API is providing a response, it's just not being displayed/parsed?

I'm still very green with Jquery and the Facebook API, so I may be overlooking something simple but essentially I'm wondering if there is an obvious reason this script would have stopped working yesterday (April 8 2015)?

I have searched the web for any changes or features of the API that Facebook may have removed but was unable to find anything that looked relevant.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should really post a bug on that Github repo, that said, my guess would be that something about the format of the json response from facebook has changed, it could even be something minor. Do you happen to have an example of a json response from when it was working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 56 of `facebook_wall.plugin.js` change `if (this.is_hidden === undefined)`  to `if (this.is_hidden === false)`

See this modified and working copy of the creator's demo http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/facebook-wall/index.html

---

#### To find this error I took the following steps:

- Navigated to the github page you linked to and subsequently the demo posted there
- Observed that it, as you stated, was also not working
- Opened the developer tools in chrome
- Verified that, as you stated, the FB API was responding with post info
- On the source tab, I went to the `facebook_wall.plugin.js` file

#### The following are steps numbered with the image attached below

1. Found the ajax call code
2. Found the first line that *should* output some data
3. Set a breakpoint at that line and refreshed the page, noting that the breakpoint was never hit meaning the code wasn't being called
4. I then found the `if` statement above this piece of code and set a breakpoint there and refreshed the page again
5. When the page refreshed the code paused on the breakpoint and I hovered over the `this` variable which makes a popup appear showing the value of the variable
6. I looked for `is_hidden` in the list and saw that it was set to `false` not `undefined`

To test my theory, I downloaded a copy of the demo website and modified the if statement to check for false and confirmed that this fixed the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much!

It would have taken me forever to figure that out for myself... 

You've saved me a huge amount of head-scratching and for that I am truly grateful.

If it's not too much trouble - for the benefit of myself and others with similar issues - would you be able to give us a quick rundown of the process you followed to arrive at that solution? Or was it simply your existing knowledge of Jquery API?

Did you find a mention of that in changelog or similar from Facebook Devs?

Either way, you sir are a legend!

Comment: FYI, I also posted the issue and the fix on the Github repo's issues page